# Modify Mongoose Object in Post Hooks

Tags: mongoose

I want to modify mongoose object in post hooks like post findOneAndUpdate, but since it is mongoose object I cannot add any property to it like in the following example

```
MyShema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(doc) {
    doc["new_field"] = 2;
    return doc;
});
```

this  doc returned is not having new_field, how do I go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else in the same situation following worked for me

```
MyShema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(doc) {
   doc.set("new_field", 2, {strict: false});
   doc.set({set: true})
});
```

The strict mode is true which does not allow to add new key-val we have to disable to add key

Answer (score 0):

What I found working is the transform property of the mongoose which does something similar

```
    if (!Myschema.options.toObject) Myschema.options.toObject = {};
    Myschema.options.toObject.transform = (doc, modified_doc) => {
        modified_doc["new_field"] = 2;
        return modified_doc;
    };
```