# Mongoose: Edit result of query in post find/findOne hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to edit my query result in the mongoose post find/findOne hook. The hook gets fired and I'm also getting the result in `this` and the input variable but I'm not able to pass on a changed version.

My post hook looks like the following:

```
Modul.post('find', function(result){
    for (const key in doc) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(doc, key) && (populate[key] && populate[key].languageVariant)) {
            if (doc[key] instanceof Array && doc[key].length == 1) doc[key] = doc[key][0];
        }
    }
    return doc;
})
```

I already tried to use the next function

```
Modul.post('find', function(result, next){
    for (const key in doc) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(doc, key) && (populate[key] && populate[key].languageVariant)) {
            if (doc[key] instanceof Array && doc[key].length == 1) doc[key] = doc[key][0];
        }
    }
    next(null, doc);
})
```

Furthermore tried the approach shown here [Modify Mongoose Object in Post Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362113/modify-mongoose-object-in-post-hooks)

```
Modul.post('find', function(result){
    for (const key in doc) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(doc, key) && (populate[key] && populate[key].languageVariant)) {
            if (doc[key] instanceof Array && doc[key].length == 1) doc.set(key, doc[key][0], {strict: false});
        }
    }
    doc.set({set: true})
})
```

The last approach got me so far that I was able to change a single value but I was not able to add this to the loop.

Before there is any confusion, I checked the loop and the if statement and both were working fine and I even got the correct value right before the end of the function.